# AdressOf method signature

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, begininvoke

Since I can't put in parameters, how can I respect the following signature?

```
Private Sub SetFocusToRow(ByRef ultraGridRow As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow)
    grdSoldeOuverture.ActiveCell = ultraGridRow.Cells(0)
    grdSoldeOuverture.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode)
End Sub
```

When I call it like this

```
Me.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.SetFocusToTemplateAddRow))
```

---

I'm on .NET 2.0 in Visual Studio 2005 with Microsoft Visual Basic 2005 so a lambda expression is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda to capture the requirements and pass them in:

```
Foo arg = GetTheFoo()

BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() SetFoo(arg)))
```

---

Edit:

First, change your method to not pass `ByRef` - this is unnecessary:

```
Private Sub SetFocusToRow(ByVal ultraGridRow As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow)
    grdSoldeOuverture.ActiveCell = ultraGridRow.Cells(0)
    grdSoldeOuverture.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode)
End Sub
```

Next, define a delegate:

```
' Define your delegate:
Delegate Sub SetFocusToRowDelegate(ByVal ultraGridRow As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow)
```

Then you can call via:

```
BeginInvoke(new SetFocusToRowDelegate(AddressOf SetFocusToRow), arg)
```

Comment: If I recall correctly lambdas didn't exist in Framework 2.0 right ? Forgot to mention my framework didn't know I had to use lambda...

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Lambdas are a compiler feature so you might not need framework support for them (to be fair I’m unsure at the moment), just a modern VB compiler. Would this be possible for you?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Okay - just edited to show the "normal" old school way of using Control.BeginInvoke...

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Did you spell it right?  Your question has AddressOf misspelled...  Can you show your exact code?  The above should work, provided you defined the delegate properly...

Comment: I would have noticed if the errore was with the spelling... I updated my question with the full original code.. How can I change it so that it works ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the `ByRef` part i'm new to Vb. What is arg in this context ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk The ultraGridRow  you want to set focus to

Answer (score 2):

Since lambdas cause a problem you could try implementing them manually using an object:

```
Class FooCurry

    Private bar as Foo

    Private Sub new (foo as Foo)
       bar = foo
    End Sub

    Public sub DoFoo()
       bar.SetFoo()
    EndSub
End Class

dim foocurry as new FooCurry(foo)
BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AdressOf foocurry.DoFoo))
```

This is how lambdas are implemented under the hood, so this should work. You could generalise the object to take a delegate and use it in more places.

Comment: Thanks this is a nice approach.. but a bit overkill for what I want to do... I guess I could find another way without the BeginInvoke... 
So this is my only option ?

Comment: This is a lot harder than just defining a custom delegate type, and using the BeginInvoke overload that takes params...

Comment: Yes but is the first thing to come into my head when he said he couldn't use lamdas, implement them as vb does under the hood